# What are good ways to visualize budget/financial controlling data?

Tags: data-visualization, finance

What are useful visualizations of budget/forecast vs actual spending data, i.e. data consisting of hierarchically structured sums compared at various (2-4) points in time? The aim would be to make operational decisions in teams about financial spendings easier.